# VB.NET Expression Expected

Tags: asp.net

When I do the following I get a message saying Expression Expected

```
     If (Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Item.DataItem("DueDate")) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Item.DataItem("ActualDate"))) ) Then


     End If
```

Comment: Note that if you are more familiar with C#, you can generally get good results with the [C# to VB.Net Converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).

Comment: As a side note, you can get rid of some of the parentheses (for readability) if you use `Not <expr> Or Not <expr>` instead of `Not (<expr> And <expr>)`, by [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is VB.NET then the AND operator is **AndAlso**

`AndAlso` and it's brother `OrElse` are better because:

- Avoids executing part of a logical expression to avoid problems.
- Code optimization by not executing any more of a compound expression
  than required

So your code should be

```
If (Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Item.DataItem("DueDate")) AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Item.DataItem("ActualDate"))) ) Then 

    .... 
End If
```

Comment: It's AndAlso (short-circuited And). OrElse is short-circuited Or

Comment: guess I was answering at the same time and wanted to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

Instead of && use AndAlso